# Include a different jar for x86 and x64 bit operating systems

Tags: java, qt, jar, x86, 64-bit

Is there a way in Java to determine if the software is run on an x86 or x64 operating system - and in function of that - include a different jar during runtime?

I am using qtjambi and they wrap the QT c and c++ libraries in an xxx_x86.jar and xxx_x64.jar

Answer (score 1):

You can find if the JRE is 32 or 64 bit by looking at the "os.arch" system property

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy with [WebStart](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp) you can specify platform-specific JARs in the [JNLP file](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/ref.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Is this also possible when I don´t use WebStart? Do you have any idea how this is solved in WebStart?

Thanks!